# How to set contributor role after creating a new azure subscription?

Tags: c#, rest, azure

I've created a new subscription using the microsoft CREST API with the following code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
SATokenFormatReseller SA_Token = GetSAResellerToken();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + SA_Token.access_token;
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
client.Headers.Add("api-version", ApiVersion);
client.Headers.Add("x-ms-correlation-id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
client.Headers.Add("x-ms-tracking-id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
var reqOrderObj = CreateReqOrderObject(service, mpn);
var reqOrderJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reqOrderObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
string res = client.UploadString("https://api.cp.microsoft.com/" + TenantId + "/orders", "POST", reqOrderJson);
```

after creating successfully the subscription, I'm trying to set contributor role for the new subscription using the management azure core api, in this way:

```
public bool CreateRoleAssignment(string subscriptionId, string tenantId, string principalId)
{
    bool roleGranted = false;
    var azureToken = GetAzureAuthTokenForCustomerTenant(NativeClientId, PartnerCenterUser, PartnerCenterPassword, tenantId);
    string responseContent = String.Empty;
    var roleAssignmentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
    var correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/{1}?api-version=2015-07-01", subscriptionId, roleAssignmentId));

    request.Method = "PUT";
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-correlation-id", correlationId);
    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-tracking-id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + azureToken.AccessToken);

    string content = Json.Encode(CreateRoleAssignmentRequestData(subscriptionId, principalId));

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(content);
    }

    try
    {
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            roleGranted = true;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException webException)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(webException.Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            roleGranted = false;
        }
    }

    return roleGranted;
}
```

but the response is that the subscription does not exist.

After some time, if I run the same piece of code (CreateRoleAssignment), the role is given succesfully to the subscription.

How could I achive this process after creating the subscription?

Comment: Could it be because that it takes some time for the subscription to become active? When I sign up for a new subscription, I am told that it may take up to 30 minutes for the subscription to become active.

Comment: Exactly, I wonder this is the problem, but how can I manage this situations, should I have a solution progammaticaly? Some kind of asynchronous polling or parallel task maybe?

Comment: I would say keep on async polling.

Comment: Could you please give me some example of how to do it? I've never worked with asynchronous polling. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically you keep on calling this function and check the web exception status. If you get a 404 (or some other error), simply put your application to sleep for some time (say a minute) and then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GauravMantri said, using async polling as the sample code below.

```
var azureToken = GetAzureAuthTokenForCustomerTenant(NativeClientId, PartnerCenterUser, PartnerCenterPassword, tenantId);
string responseContent = String.Empty;
var roleAssignmentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
var correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string url = string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/{1}?api-version=2015-07-01", subscriptionId, roleAssignmentId);
string content = Json.Encode(CreateRoleAssignmentRequestData(subscriptionId, principalId));

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-correlation-id", correlationId);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-tracking-id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + azureToken.AccessToken);
    var response = await client.PutAsync(url, content);
    while(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
    {
        response = await client.PutAsync(url, content);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```